# Is there a Python function to get coordinates from an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, vectorization

I was wondering if there's a way to take an image like the Pentagon below and translate it into an array of points `(x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2...)` like:

```
(1,3,
2,6,
6,6,
7,3,
4,1)
```

With a coordinate system rooted in the top left. I know you can convert an image into array using opencv but that would translate each pixel into an element of the array. I'm looking to get just the non white elements and only the critical points of them (i.e. where they change direction).

Pentagon:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is something there, but I'm not aware of it. You can, however, use the Hough transform with Scikit-learn, to detect the straight lines: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html . Then you'd have to calculate the start and end point of the lines, or more likely, find out where they intersect, to get your (pixel) coordinates of the corners. At least, I assume you want the coordinates of the corners of such a figure as the pentagon.

Comment: You can do corner detection using cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541

Comment: Alternately, get contours and then reduce the contour points using cv2.approxPolyDP(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()` method to detect the corners of an image:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png", 0)

for (x, y) in cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(img, 5, 0.01, 20)[:, 0].astype("int0"):
    cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 27, 127, -1)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

The positional arguments of the `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()` method are:

- `image` 8-bit or floating-point 32-bit, single-channel image
- `maxCorners` Maximum number of corners to return. If there are more corners than are found, the strongest of them is returned. `maxCorners <= 0` implies that no limit on the maximum is set and all detected corners are returned.
- `qualityLevel` Parameter characterizing the minimal accepted quality of image corners. The parameter value is multiplied by the best corner quality measure, which is the minimal eigenvalue or the Harris function response. The corners with the quality measure less than the product are rejected.
- `minDistance` Minimum possible Euclidean distance between the returned corners.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV by getting the largest external contour and reducing the vertices.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("pentagon.png")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# get the largest external contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
peri = cv2.arcLength(big_contour, True)

# reduce to fewer vertices on polygon
poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(big_contour, 0.01 * peri, False)

# list polygon points
result = img.copy()
print("Polygon Points:")
for p in poly:
    x = p[0][0]
    y = p[0][1]
    pt = str(x) + "," + str(y)
    print(pt)
    cv2.circle(result,(x,y),3,(0,0,255),-1)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("pentagon_corners.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Coordinates:

```
Polygon Points (x,y):
255,12
0,197
97,499
414,499
511,197
256,12
```